# Add a Webview Window to a existent iOS App that loads local stored HTML

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview, webview, local

Add a Webview Window to a existent iOS App that loads local stored HTML ... i am working on a app that loads a feed RSS and thats already done, but now the app needs a section that can be updated on a simple manner...

Comment: Is your question 'How to add a web view?'

Comment: Actually at the time, i was trying to add a screen to an app, that already generates a webview and load content from internal resources, but in the end was easier to add such contents in the webview itself... thanks for the help guys....

Answer (score 1):

Your going to want to just drop a webview on in your xib, attatch it through your IBOutlet property, and then load your local stored HTML like the following:

```
NSError *fileReadError = nil;
            NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"HTMLFilename" ofType:@"html"];
            NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&fileReadError];

            if ( fileContents != nil )
            {
                [self.webView loadHTMLString:fileContents baseURL:nil];
            }
```